Is there a way of ignoring @Data annotations in a Java Spring Boot application that uses SonarQube for code coverage?
I am facing an issue right now where model classes in my Java Spring Boot application that use the @Data annotation really bring down my code coverage percentage. And as far as I'm aware, Sonarqube doesn't provide a way of telling me which conditions haven't been covered.
My unit tests that I've written are already very comprehensive and detailed and I don't think I really need to go any further writing more unit tests. So is there a way I can exclude the line containing the @Data annotation from Sonarqube's analysis? Any tips appreciated.
I've tried to add as many detailed unit tests as possible to these model classes. I know the @Data annotation encompasses other annotations like ToString so I've made sure that all of my unit tests cover the annotations encompassed by @Data

why don't you exclude the model class or the whole model package from sonar coverage ? using <sonar.coverage.exclusions>

You could consider using the @Generated annotation to indicate that the code in your model classes is auto-generated and should be excluded from SonarQube's analysis.
You should take a look at this question:
what is the use of @Generated Lombok annotation

Thank you for the suggestion! The @Generated annotation did the trick
